# Android Animation overlapping bottom navigation control bar

Tags: android, transition

I have Slide up and down Animation Its overlapping Bottom Navigation Bar . Just i created new app with no other changed

slide_down_info

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p" />
```

slide_up_info

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

Mainactivity

```
texttest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up_info,R.anim.no_change);
        }
    });
```

secondActivity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.e("TAG", "onBackPressed: " );
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change,R.anim.slide_down_info);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this on a physical device? There is a chance it is happening only in the emulator.

Comment: Yes both having same issue

Comment: Try changing start and end positions measurement unit from `%p` to `%`.  `%p` looks like a wrong unit. Haven't encountered it. Make sure you use percentages for all `from...`, `to...` attributes.